# Find the coordinates of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

"A parallelogram has a peak with coordinates $(1,1)$ and two sides with the equasions $y=x-3$ and $x-4y+9=0$. Find the other $3$ peaks."

This is the problem, roughly translated from Greek. Hopefully it makes sense... I've tried drawing out a parallelogram and naming it $ABCD$ and assigning the equasions to the lines of the shape. I've used a system and found (I hope I'm right?) that $C$ is $(7,4)$. Then I tried using the distance formula to find $B$ and $D$, but it didn't work out. How do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $A(1,1)$ which does not lie on $x=y+3,y=4y-9$

So, $C(7,4)$

Now as $B$ lies on $x=y+3,$ WLOG $B(b+3,b)$

Similarly, WLOG $D(4a-9,a)$

Now use the fact : the midpoint of $AC, BD$ coincide.

i.e.,
$$\dfrac{1+7}2=\dfrac{4a-9+b+3}2\iff4a+b=14$$

and $$\dfrac{1+4}2=\dfrac{a+b}2\iff a+b=5$$

Comment: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMAT6680.F99/Wise/unit/para6/c55.htm

Answer (score 0):

$C(7,4)$ is another peak (you are right). Then you can construct two other lines (parallelogram sides):

$y=x$ parallel to $y=x-3$ and cross from point $A(1,1)$

$x-4y+3=0$ parallel to $x-4y+9=0$ and cross from point $A(1,1)$

Then find peaks $B$ and $D$ like you find $C(7,4)$.

$y=x$ and $x-4y+9=0$ gives $(3,3)$

$x-4y+3=0$ and $y=x-3$ gives $(5,2)$

Comment: I hope I don't sound too stupid, but why is y=x?

Comment: any parallel line to $y=x-3$ is $y=x+constant$ but it line shoud cross point $(1,1)$ that's why $y=x$

Comment: So if **A** would have been, let's say $(3,4)$, it would have been $4y = 3x + constant$?

Comment: no if $A(3,4)$ you'll have $y=x+1$ (in $y=x+constant $ need put $x=3$ and $y=4$ and find constant)